# How to use Handlers that don't have SomeException as their argument type

Tags: haskell, exception

When using `Control.Monad.Throw` (i.e. `exceptions` package), something that confuses me that it seem that all my my throwing and catching has to work with `SomeException`.

E.g.

```
value :: Either ExitCode String
value = throwM $ ExitFailure 23
```

This looks to me like it should compile, because `throwM :: (Exception e, MonadThrow m) => e -> m a`, and `ExitCode` has an instance of Exception. Even this doesn't compile:

```
value :: Exception e => Either e String
value = throwM $ ExitFailure 23
```

In fact, it only compiles when I change the signature to `SomeException`. I know the `Exception` type class has a special place re

In the [documentation for Control.Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html) I could see examples where they use `catches` with handlers of signature `ArithException -> m a` or similiar. I tested it and it worked.

Is this not possible when using `exceptions`?

EDIT
The error messages are either:

> Couldn't match type `ExitCode` with `SomeException` arising from a use of `throwM`

or

> Couldn't match type `e` with `SomeException` arising from a use of `throwM`

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 5):

The behavior you are seeing is from the type signature of `throwM`:

```
throwM :: (Exception e, MonadThrow m) => e -> m a
```

And the instance for `Either`, which is essentially:

```
MonadThrow (Either SomeException)
```

This makes `throwM`:

```
throwM :: (Exception e) => e -> Either SomeException a
```

`throwM` for `Either SomeException` can take any `Exception e`.

However, **there is no MonadThrow instance** for `Either ExitCode`, or for `forall e. Exception e => Either e`.

The problem is that there isn't really a way to write an instance that's polymorphic for all `e`.  Imagine having an instance

```
Exception q => MonadThrow (Either q)
```

This would make `throwM`:

```
throwM :: (Exception e, Exception q) => e -> Either q a
```

which means you have to be able to take *any* `e` and convert it into *any* `q`, which **is not possible** using the `Exception` typeclass alone.

Imagine also if there was a `MonadThrow` instance for `Either ExitCode`.  That would make the type signature for `throwM`:

```
throwM :: Exeption e => e -> Either ExitCode a
```

which you can probably see is clearly nonsensical, since there are many instances of `Exception` that cannot be coerced to an `ExitCode`. (Try writing a function with that type signature if you don't believe me!)

*If you just want* short-circuting exception behavior for `Either`, consider:

1. Just use `Left` instead of `throwM`, and pattern matching for `catch`.  If you *really* want to use `Exception` still, you can use `fromException` to attempt to coerce a `SomeException` into an `Exception` instance of your choice.
2. You can use the *exceptions* package, and catching will still work as long as you must assume that the exception could be any instance (`SomeException`)
3. Use `MonadError` and `ExceptT` from *mtl*, if you want some sort of polymorphic interface with catching ability